# MySQL very simple join example requested with subtable

Tags: php, mysql, join

I keep falling back into questions with MySQL joining.
And I would like to request a very simple example I could use to continue my journey of understanding learning the MySQL syntax.

Let's say I got the following table's

**test_testtable**

- *testtable_id*
- testtable_name
- testtable_user
- testtable_option
- testtable_textfield

**test_testlink**

- testlink_id
- *testlink_link*
- *testlink_address*

**test_address**

- *address_id*
- address_name
- address_phone
- address_email
- address_street
- address_city
- address_zip

I would like to make a selection like :

```
SELECT * (lets say I would define the fields) FROM `test_testable` 
JOIN `test_testtable`.`testtable_id` = `test_testlink`.`testlink_link`
AND
JOIN `test_testlink`.`testlink_addres` = `test_address`.`address_id`
WHERE `user_id` = 5
```

Hence the linking structure is like:

test_testtable.**testtable_id** = leading

table **test_testlink** is a table to link the table *test_testtable* and *test_address*

And linking table **test_testlink** uses the field *testlink_link* to link to the table **test_testtable**, and uses the field *testlink_address* to link to the table **test_address**

This does not work. FOR ME.. Since I continuously seem to fail of catching the correct syntax logic.

So I hope that someone could give me a small example of how to correctly implement such a simple yet critical query!

TIAD!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach :

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.id_table1 = table1.id
JOIN table3 ON table3.id_table2 = table2.id
WHERE table1.id = 10
```

For your purpose :

```
SELECT * (lets say I would define the fields) FROM `test_testable` 
JOIN `test_testlink` ON `test_testtable`.`testtable_id` = `test_testlink`.`testlink_link`
JOIN `test_address` ON `test_testlink`.`testlink_addres` = `test_address`.`address_id`
WHERE `user_id` = 5
```

[Please read the reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: I know I should avoid comments like thanks.. But this helped me that much I would still love to tell you I really appreciate this. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax. You should mention which tables to join first then based on which fields.

```
SELECT * (lets say I would define the fields) FROM `test_testable` 
INNER JOIN test_testlink 
ON `test_testtable`.`testtable_id` = `test_testlink`.`testlink_link`
INNER JOIN `test_address` 
ON `test_testlink`.`testlink_addres` = `test_address`.`address_id`
AND `test_testtable`.`user_id` = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from testlink JOIN testtable ON testlink.tableid = testtable.ID
                       JOIN testaddress ON testlink.addressid = testaddress.ID
WHERE testtable.ID = 5
```